# How to create a Devise forgot password custom mail and url from one app to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token, forgot-password

I have a management Rails app that manages the content on our main app.  I'd like to be able to create accounts for people, populate information, and send them a forgot password url in a custom email to have them start using their account.  I have everything but the forgot password url working.  This is what I have so far:

**My Action to create the forgot password token, and send the email**

```
def send_staff_member_invite
    staff_member = StaffMember.find(params[:id])
    token, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(staff_member.class, :reset_password_token)
    staff_member.reset_password_token = enc
    staff_member.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc

    if staff_member.save
      StaffMemberMailer.send_staff_member_invite_email(staff_member, token).deliver
      redirect_to staff_member_path
    else
      redirect_to send_invite_staff_member_path
    end
  end
```

**Send email action**

```
def send_staff_member_invite_email(staff_member, token)
    @staff_member = staff_member
    @company = Company.find(staff_member.company_id)
    @token = token
    mail(:to => @staff_member.email, :subject => "#{@company.name} Directory Invite")
  end
```

**The Email**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Hi <%= @staff_member.first_name %>!<br/>
    <a href="https://testapp/password/edit?reset_password_token=<%= @token %>">Click On This Link To Set Up Access To Edit Your Business Page.
    </a><br/>
    <br/>
    Thank you
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I always get the error "Reset password token is invalid."  I'm assuming it has to do with creating the token for one app on another possibly?  Anyone know what could be causing it to always be invalid?

Comment: Not the direct answer but you could simplify this using [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)

Comment: seems not to be possible; the token won't match

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? The value of @token doesn't match for different apps.